# Determine playing card

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, random, playing-cards

I would like a code review on the coding I did for my assignment. The reason I have asked here is because my lecturer has no intention of going through (Don't ask me why, I asked before and he said no..) and I have no idea if I am doing it right or not.. All my other classmates seems to have different answers too, some have deck class, shuffle function etc..

Anyway the question is asking the user *to design and implement a class that represent a playing card in which it can be used to play card games. Consider what information you needs to be stored in a card and what you man want to do with a card (accessors/mutators).*

In this assignment, only 2 files are required - 1 header and 1 implementation file.
Kindly see the following:

Header file

```
#ifndef  CARD_H
#define  CARD_H
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class card
{
    private:
        string cardSuit;
        string cardValue;

    public:
        // Constructor
        string displayCard(string, string);

        // Member Functions
        string getSuit();
        string getValue();

        // Default
        card();

};
#endif
```

Implementation File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "card.h"

using namespace std;


card::card()
{
    srand(time(0));
    cardSuit = getSuit();
    cardValue = getValue();
}


string card::displayCard(string suit, string value)
{
    return cardSuit + " of " + cardValue;
}


string card::getSuit()
{

    string arrSuits[] = {"HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS", "SPADES"};

    // 1 out of 4 suits is choose randomly
    int randSuits = rand() % 4;
    return arrSuits[randSuits];
}

string card::getValue()
{
    string arrValues[] = {"ACE", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING"};

    // 1 out of 13 values is choose randomly
    int randValues = rand() % 13;

    return arrValues[randValues];
}
```

As I have only started out in C++, do pardon me if my coding format is wrong etc.

Answer (score 3):

In object-oriented programming, a `card` object is supposed to represent a card.  Your `card`, though… I'm not sure what it represents!  If anything, it's the ultimate chameleon card: every time you call `.getSuit()` or `.getValue()` on it, it reports a different value!

The card's identity, therefore, must be determined in the constructor, and it should never change thereafter.  All three methods should be declared `const`.

Furthermore, it's a bad idea to have the card's identity be randomly assigned in the constructor.  How would you create a deck of 52 different cards, if you couldn't instantiate each one deterministically?

The `displayCard()` method makes no sense — why should you pass in `suit` and `value` as parameters, which will then be ignored?

`using namespace std;` defeats the purpose of the `std` namespace.  It's sloppy practice in general.  In particular, you should *never* do that in a header file, because any .cpp file that includes that header will have its namespace contaminated as well.

Your comments are wrong: `displayCard()` is not a constructor.

So, the header file should look more like this:

```
#ifndef  CARD_H
#define  CARD_H
#include <string>

class Card
{
    public:
        // Constructor
        Card(const std::string &suit, const std::string &value);

        // Member Functions
        std::string getSuit() const;
        std::string getValue() const;
        std::string display() const;

    private:
        std::string suit, value;
};
#endif
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out what the implementation should look like.

Comment: Then I suppose what I have done is totally wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what 200_success answered, I think it would improve the implementation if you create a enum to specify the valid suits (you can also do the same with the values). This way when creating a card you are forced to used a valid Suit.

```
class Card
{
public:
    enum Suits
    {
         E_SPADES,
         E_HEARTS,
         E_DIAMONDS,
         E_CLUBS
    }
    // Constructor
    Card(const Suits &suit, const std::string &value);

    // Member Functions
    Suits getSuit() const;
    std::string getValue() const;
    std::string display() const;

private:
    Suits suit; 
    std::string value;
};
```